# Could not find server error when parsing the import query

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, ssis, etl

I'm trying to create a new import SSIS package on my production server. I'm receiving an error that I didn't receive on my development server.

I'm using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard launched from within SSMS. I right-clicked the database I want to import data into, chose tasks, and then Import Data. I selected the data source using the SQL Server Native Client. Then I selected the destination, again using the SQL Server Native Client. The next screen I selected use a query. I imported the query that I used in my development system and just changed which database to look at. When I click on Parse I receive this message:
Deferred prepare could not be completed. Statement(s) could not be prepared. Could not find server ''  in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Source is on another machine, different SQL instance. Destination is the server that is showing up in the error message.

This is the query that is working in development, but not production:

```
DECLARE
    @lasttran_num INT

select 
    @lasttran_num = last_tran
from DB01.ATR_App_plt2.dbo.lasttran_mst
where lasttran_mst.lasttran_key = 5000

select ID, CAST(Coil AS nvarchar(15)) as 'Lot', KgNetWt, TCode, TransactionDateTime
from Transactions trx
where trx.ID > @lasttran_num
```

I know this is working in development because I set up a job to run the SSIS package for 2 weeks. Checked it daily and it was, indeed, importing the new records.

Comment: Never mind... I had to add DB01 as a linked server on the source instance. I didn't think we had to used linked servers with the import/export wizard.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is 4-part name:

```
DB01.ATR_App_plt2.dbo.lasttran_mst
```

`DB01` is SQL Server instance and most likely it is different on PROD env

Comment: I couldn't get the query to work without a 4-part name. Can you help me understand how I could have written the query differently so I can avoid this in the future?

Comment: @MaryMartin If you really need to use 4 part name you should use the one that is used on production

Comment: I actually went the 4-part name route because I kept getting errors when I tried anything else in the query. In order for this to work I need to get the value of a column found in the destination database, then use that value to limit the records returned from the source database.